# sqlalchemy exists for query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exists

How do I check whether data in a query exists?

For example:

```
users_query = User.query.filter_by(email='x@x.com')
```

How I can check whether users with that email exist?

I can check this with

```
users_query.count()
```

but how to check it with **exists**?

Answer (score 101):

The following solution is a bit simpler:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists

print session.query(exists().where(User.email == '...')).scalar()
```

Comment: Note that this would give wrong results for polymorphic types. When filtering on both parent and child attributes, the resulting query will select from cartesian product (outer join) of tables. To fix it, you should manually set `FROM` clause via `select_from`: 

`e = exists(select([1]).select_from(User).where(and_(User.email == '...', ...))).select()`

Comment: @aikoven: your suggestion results in a `Every derived table must have its own alias` error. Adding `exists(…).select().alias('foo')` fixed it (see [alias()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.alias) function).

Answer (score 42):

The most acceptable and readable option for me is

```
session.query(<Exists instance>).scalar()
```

like

```
session.query(User.query.filter(User.id == 1).exists()).scalar()
```

which returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: Also, note that some databases such as SQL Server don’t allow an EXISTS expression to be present in the columns clause of a SELECT. To select a simple boolean value based on the exists as a WHERE, use sqlalchemy.literal: `session.query(literal(True)).filter(q.exists()).scalar()`

Comment: This throws following exception: `AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'`

Comment: The `.query` attribute is *specific to Flask-SQLAlchemy*. You'd use `session.query(session.query(User).filter(User.id == 1).exists()).scalar()`.

Answer (score 16):

There is no way that I know of to do this using the orm query api. But you can drop to a level lower and use [exists](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) from sqlalchemy.sql.expression:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select, exists

users_exists_select = select((exists(users_query.statement),)) 
print engine.execute(users_exists_select).scalar()
```

Answer (score 15):

**2021 Answer for SqlAlchemy 1.4**

Refrain from calling `.query` and instead use `select` directly chained with `.exists` as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import select

stmt = select(User).where(User.email=="x@x.com").exists()
```

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists

Comment: This is SqlAlchemy 1.4

Comment: Attempting to execute this will result in an error because Exists is a clause, not a statement. You need to wrap it in `select()`.

Answer (score 4):

For **SQL Server**, I had to do this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal

result = session.query(literal(True)).filter(
    session.query(User)
    .filter_by(email='...')
    .exists()
).scalar()
print(result is not None)

# Resulting query:
# SELECT 1
# WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
# FROM User
# WHERE User.email = '...')
```

But it's much **simpler** without `EXISTS`:

```
result = (
    session.query(literal(True))
    .filter(User.email == '...')
    .first()
)
print(result is not None)

# Resulting query:
# SELECT TOP 1 1
# FROM User
# WHERE User.email = '...'
```

Comment: Same for **Oracle 12c**. Thank you for the solution

Comment: `session.query(cls).filter_by(**kwargs).first() is not None` would also work, without importing `literal`, at least for MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in **SQLAlchemy 1.4/2.0** with the new [unified API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#orm-query-unified-with-core-select):

```py
from sqlalchemy import exists


session.scalar(
    exists()
    .where(User.email == 'x@x.com')
    .select()
)
```

Answer (score -3):

it can be done:

```
from sqlalchemy import select

user = session.scalars(
    select(User).where(User.email=="x@x.com")
).first()

if user:
    pass
else:
    pass
```