# Flask-SQLAlchemy check if row exists in table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application which uses Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to a MySQL database.

I would like to be able to check whether a row is present in a table. How would I modify a query like so to check the row exists:

```
db.session.query(User).filter_by(name='John Smith')
```

I found a solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336408/2961662) which uses SQLAlchemy but does not seem to fit with the way Flask-SQLAlchemy works:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists    
print session.query(exists().where(User.email == '...')).scalar()
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what way does the first query *not* check that the row exists?

Comment: I would like the query to return `True` or `False` if the row exists.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Since you only want to see if the user exists, you don't want to query the entire object. Only query the id, it exists if the scalar return is not None.

```
exists = db.session.query(User.id).filter_by(name='davidism').first() is not None
```

```sql
SELECT user.id AS user_id 
FROM user 
WHERE user.name = ?
```

If you know `name` (or whatever field you're querying) is unique, you can use `scalar` instead of `first`.

The second query you showed also works fine, Flask-SQLAlchemy does nothing to prevent any type of query that SQLAlchemy can make. This returns `False` or `True` instead of `None` or an id like above, but it is *slightly* more expensive because it uses a subquery.

```
exists = db.session.query(db.exists().where(User.name == 'davidism')).scalar()
```

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE user.name = ?) AS anon_1
```

Answer (score 32):

Wrap a `.exists()` query in another `session.query()` with a `scalar()` call at the end. SQLAlchemy will produce an optimized `EXISTS` query that returns `True` or `False`.

```
exists = db.session.query(
    db.session.query(User).filter_by(name='John Smith').exists()
).scalar()
```

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM user 
WHERE user.name = ?) AS anon_1
```

While it's *potentially* more expensive due to the subquery, it's more clear about what's being queried. It may also be preferable over `db.exists().where(...)` because it selects a constant instead of the full row.

Answer (score 32):

```
bool(User.query.filter_by(name='John Smith').first())
```

It will return `False` if objects with this name doesn't exist and `True` if it exists.

Comment: I found this answer useful, but I had to change it to `bool(session.query(User).filter_by(name='John Smith').first())`

Comment: It's working, but there is no need to fetch the whole User just to find if it exists.

Answer (score -8):

Think there is a typo in davidism's answer, this works for me:

```
exists = db.session.query(**User**).filter_by(name='davidism').scalar() is not None
```

Comment: I don't think adding asterisks in the `User` part helps.

Comment: Note that if you find a typo in an answer, you can suggest an edit rather than adding another answer.