# Flask-SQLAlchemy check if table exists in database

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLAlchemy check if table exists in database.
I see similar problems, but I try not to succeed.

[Flask-SQLAlchemy check if row exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938475/flask-sqlalchemy-check-if-row-exists-in-table)

I have create a table object ,like this:

```
<class'flask_sqlalchemy.XXX'>,
```

now how to check the object if exists in database.

I do many try:
eg:

```
   for t in db.metadata.sorted_tables:
            print("tablename",t.name)
```

some table object is created before,but it doesnt exists in database,and now they. all print.
eg:print content is

```
tablename： table_1
tablename： table_2
tablename： table_3
```

but only table_1 is exist datable，table_2 and table_3 is dynamica create，now I only want use the table_1.

very thanks.

Comment: Use `MetaData` from `sqlalchemy` : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html

Comment: I try, but cant, I update the prolem,thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you want to edit `table_1` ?

Answer (score 7):

I used these methods. Looking at the model like you did only tells you what SHOULD be in the database.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

def database_is_empty():
    table_names = sa.inspect(engine).get_table_names()
    is_empty = table_names == []
    print('Db is empty: {}'.format(is_empty))
    return is_empty

def table_exists(name):
    ret = engine.dialect.has_table(engine, name)
    print('Table "{}" exists: {}'.format(name, ret))
    return ret
```

There may be a simpler method than this:

```
def model_exists(model_class):
    engine = db.get_engine(bind=model_class.__bind_key__)
    return model_class.metadata.tables[model_class.__tablename__].exists(engine)
```

Comment: Note: `engine` reference isn't defined

Comment: Notev2: `engine` reference can be obtained from `SQLAlchemy()`. Also import `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

Comment: Table.exists() method has been deprecated since version 1.4

Comment: @ZobayerHasan It might be useful to mention what replaces it.

Comment: The documentation of [dialect.has_table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.engine.default.DefaultDialect.has_table)() says that *"This method is used internally by SQLAlchemy, and is published so that third-party dialects may provide an implementation. It is **not** the public API for checking for table presence. Please use the Inspector.has_table() method."*

Comment: @PaulRougieux Thanks for the update. `Inspector.has_table()` was added 2 years after this answer according to the docs. Please add an answer using it so we can point people to the newer, more correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

the solution is too easy, just write this two rows in you code and it should work fine for you

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, inspect

...

inspector = inspect(db.engine)
print(inspector.has_table("user")) # output: Boolean
```

have a nice day

Comment: flask_sqlalchemy doesn't have `inspect` I'm getting: `ImportError: cannot import name 'inspect' from 'flask_sqlalchemy'`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Alchemy's recommended way to check for the presence of a table is to create an inspector object and use its `has_table()` method.
The following example was copied from [sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.has_table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.has_table), with the addition of an SQLite engine (in memory) to make it reproducible:

```
In [17]: from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
    ...: from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Text
    ...: engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    ...: meta = MetaData()
    ...: meta.bind = engine
    ...: user_table = Table('user', meta, Column("first_name", Text))
    ...: user_table.create()
    ...: inspector = inspect(engine)
    ...: inspector.has_table('user')
Out[17]: True
```

You can also use the `user_table` metadata element `name` to check if it exists as such:

```
inspector.has_table(user_table.name)
```