# SQLAlchemy, prevent duplicate rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering if it's possible to prevent committing duplicates to the database. For example, presume there is a class as follows

```
class Employee(Base):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String)
```

If I were to make a series of these objects,

```
employee1 = Employee(name='bob')
employee2 = Employee(name='bob')

session.add_all([employee1, employee2])
session.commit()
```

I would like only a single row to be added to the database, and `employee1` and `employee2` to point to the same object in memory (if possible).

Is there functionality within SQLAlchemy to accomplish this? Or would I need to ensure duplicates don't exist programmatically?

Comment: It sounds like you have the wrong primary key. You should make the name the primary key if that's what you want. Though then people can't really change names without incurring a huge multi-table database update as all the foreign keys everywhere have to change. Also, what happens if you try to change a name to an existing one? Would you just want to wipe out the row that's already there?

Comment: Creating a unique index by name, even if it's not the primary key, looks like the right way to enforce name uniqueness.

Comment: To prevent committing duplicates do what @9000 said. To have the session only create bob once in your second example, see the [unique object recipes](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject).

Comment: Using a unique constraint or primary key would prevent duplicates from being added, but it would do so by preventing the new rows from being committed. I would like the database to resolve the issue rather than just prevent the commit from happening

Comment: @nven - And how would the database resolve the issue other than by preventing the commit from happening?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the ORM to realize that there are duplicate entries, only commit one, and have all references to the duplicates reference the same object

Answer (score 5):

An alternate `get_or_create()` solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound
# ...

def get_or_create(self, model, **kwargs):
    """
    Usage:
    class Employee(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'employee'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String, unique=True)

    get_or_create(Employee, name='bob')
    """
    instance = get_instance(model, **kwargs)
    if instance is None:
        instance = create_instance(model, **kwargs)
    return instance


def create_instance(model, **kwargs):
    """create instance"""
    try:
        instance = model(**kwargs)
        sess.add(instance)
        sess.flush()
    except Exception as msg:
        mtext = 'model:{}, args:{} => msg:{}'
        log.error(mtext.format(model, kwargs, msg))
        sess.rollback()
        raise(msg)
    return instance


def get_instance(self, model, **kwargs):
    """Return first instance found."""
    try:
        return sess.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    except NoResultFound:
        return
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a class method to get or create an `Employee` -- get it if it exists, otherwise create:

```
@classmethod
def get_or_create(cls, name):
    exists = db.session.query(Employee.id).filter_by(name=name).scalar() is not None
    if exists:
        return db.session.query(Employee).filter_by(name=name).first()
    return cls(name=name)


employee1 = Employee(name='bob')
db.session.add(employee1)
employee2 = Employee(name='bob')

employee1 == employee2  # False


bob1 = Employee.get_or_create(name='bob')
if bob1 not in db.session:
    db.session.add(bob1)

len(add_to_session) # 1

bob2 = Employee.get_or_create(name='bob')
if bob2 not in db.session:
    db.session.add(bob2)

len(add_to_session) # 1

bob1 == bob2  # True
```

Comment: credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952421/4386191 for the quick `exists` expression.

Comment: This is interesting. I was hoping for a way to resolve this on commit. I presume bob1 would need to first be added to the session before `get_or_create` would return the `bob1` object to the `bob2 = Employee.get_or_create(name='bob')` call? In the current workflow of my package, I first generate a large list of these types of objects and am not interacting with the database at all until commit

Comment: @nven oops, you're right that it has to be added to the session.  I added this to the example and showed a pattern that might work for you.  No commit needed, just add objects to the session after checking for uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 approaches:

- The database approach: create a relevant primary key; with SQLAlchemy you would define e.g. based on your minimalistic example `name = Column('First Name', String(20), primary_key=True)`
- The coding approach: check whether the attribute, set of attributes already exists in the table, otherwise create it. See relevant code examples [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/UniqueObject).

In terms of performance, I believe the database approach is better. It also is the one which makes more sense.

Comment: can't edit the answer above, so will add the updated link here:
the article that @tagoma has provided above has moved to:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/UniqueObject