# Flask-SQLAlchemy Check if row exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

*I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938475/flask-sqlalchemy-check-if-row-exists-in-table) SO question, so far it has not helped.*

So I am trying to check if a row exists in a table with Flask-SQLAlchemy, and so far nothing has helped.

My current code:

```
@app.route('/guilds/<guildid>')
def guildsettings(guildid):
    discord = make_session(token=session.get('oauth2_token'))
    user = discord.get(API_BASE_URL + '/users/@me').json()
    guilds = discord.get(API_BASE_URL + '/users/@me/guilds').json()
    row = Settings.query.all()
    exists = Settings.query.filter_by(db.exists().where(Settings.guildid==guildid)).scalar()
    print(exists)
    if exists == True:
        info = Settings.query.filter_by(guildid=guildid).first()
        return render_template("guild.html", id=guildid, guilds=guilds, User=user, prefix=info.prefix, logschannel=info.logschannel, modrole=info.modrole, adminrole=info.adminrole, welcomechannel=info.welcomechannel, welcomemessage=info.welcomemessage, dadbot=info.dadbot, music=info.music, funcmds=info.funcmds, weather=info.weather, wapikey=info.wapikey)
    else:
        return render_template("notinserver.html", guildid=guildid, link="https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&permissions=8&redirect_uri=xxxxxxx%2Fme&scope=bot&guild_id={}".format(guildid))
```

I am not sure on what to do now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is happening with your code? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it needs to be excactly one result:

```
try:
    Settings.query.filter_by(db.exists().where(Settings.guildid==guildid)).one()
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
    return False
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound:
    #do what ever you want to do if there is more than one result
return True
```

Comment: I need it to check if the row with the specific `guildid` exists. If it doesn't then it should redirect to the link. If it does, it should render the `guild.html` template.

Comment: just replace flase/true with redirect/render. did it work or do you still need help?