# How can I check to see if some data exists and return a boolean value using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a flask web-app using SQLAlchemy. How can I check to see if some data exists and if it exists return True and vice-versa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy exists for query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646173/sqlalchemy-exists-for-query)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that :

`exists = db.session.query(your_id).filter_by(your_filter).scalar() is not None`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do something like this:

```
def check_exists():
    return True if session.query(data).filter().one() else False
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it as :

```
exist_query = db.session.query(model).filter_by(column = some_val).exists()
if db.session.query(exist_query).scalar():
    # implement logic here
```

Note:
The db.session.query(exist_query).scalar() gives the boolean value while the exist_query is a query object .